# Git filter-branch, variables, and bash

Tags: git, bash

Im not sure if this is a bash issue or git issue but I am completely stumped.

I have the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=testfile.c

sha1=`git log --pretty=oneline --branches -- $FILE | tail -1 | cut -f 1 -d' '`
sha2=044ec18c3c4efe9ef44daf7479b9f71d89720690

echo "sha1=.$sha1."
echo "sha2=.$sha2."

git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch '"$FILE"'' -- ${sha1}^..
```

Which fails with the following output:

```
$> ./script.sh
sha1=.044ec18c3c4efe9ef44daf7479b9f71d89720690.
sha2=.044ec18c3c4efe9ef44daf7479b9f71d89720690.
fatal: ambiguous argument '044ec18c3c4efe9ef44daf7479b9f71d89720690^..': unknown
revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions
```

But if I simply change the script by using `sha2` instead of `sha1` on the `git filter-branch` line, it works and generates the following output:

```
$> ./script.sh
sha1=.044ec18c3c4efe9ef44daf7479b9f71d89720690.
sha2=.044ec18c3c4efe9ef44daf7479b9f71d89720690.
Rewrite 044ec18c3c4efe9ef44daf7479b9f71d89720690 (1/1139)rm 'talairach_avi/SVIP_Child_Comp_N24_as_orig.4dfp.img'
Rewrite d30e314d7b6e2f62fa26e62dc83fc5083b92085b (2/1139)rm 'talairach_avi/SVIP_Child_Comp_N24_as_orig.4dfp.img'
Rewrite f2897cd0d17b75de70aca1baa70e6cb40243d0a1 (3/1139)rm 'talairach_avi/SVIP_Child_Comp_N24_as_orig.4dfp.img'
...
```

`sha1` and `sha2` have the exact same value. Why does using the hard-coded `sha2` variable work, but the assigned variable of `sha1` not work? How can I get it to work with `sha1`? Ive tried every possible permutation/combination of single and double quotes to no avail.

I would very greatly appreciate any input on the matter. Thanks.

**EDIT1:**
Although the echo statements alone appear identical, piping the output of echo through `od` produces different output:

```
$> echo $sha1 | od -x
0000000 5b1b 3333 306d 3434 6365 3831 3363 3463
0000020 6665 3965 6665 3434 6164 3766 3734 6239
0000040 6639 3137 3864 3739 3032 3936 1b30 6d5b
0000060 000a
0000061

$> eco $sha2 | od -x
0000000 3430 6534 3163 6338 6333 6534 6566 6539
0000020 3466 6434 6661 3437 3937 3962 3766 6431
0000040 3938 3237 3630 3039 000a
0000051
```

**EDIT2: SOLVED** As can be seen by the comments below, the issue was solved with git configuration for coloured output. Unsetting this configuration solved the issue. `git config --global color.ui false`

Comment: I would presume it would have something to do with nonprinting characters and quoting -- try wrapping both of the assignments in double-quotes (sha1="`...`"; etc), as well as the path in the final command `-- "${sha1}^.."`.  See if that changes anything.

Comment: @zebediah49 I tried exactly as you suggested and it still fails when using `sha1` and not when using `sha2` :(

Comment: My first target would be nonprintables too. Pipe the echo output through `od -x` and see if the results are still identical.

Comment: @Harald Indeed you are correct. Piping the output of `echo $sha1` and `echo $sha2` through `od -x` gives different output. Any idea what I need to do to fix the `sha1` assignment?

Comment: Well, show the output of od. What is it that gets in the way? Add the output to your question.

Comment: @Harald Added output to original question.

Comment: Those are color strings.  Do you have some forced color specifiers somewhere, in your git configuration or with an alias turning `git log` into `git log --color`?

Comment: @torek That's it right there! Removing the colors from my git config solved the issue. `git config --global color.ui false`. What a nightmare. I would have never figured this out on my own, thanks to all for your assistance.

Comment: Odd, `color.ui` is still supposed to respect the tty-ness of the output device, even if set to `always`.  This works correctly in my git 2.0.2 installation.

Comment: @torek Im using git v1.7.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to be color strings (`%C(yellow)` and a corresponding `%C(reset)`, more or less) getting forced into the `git log` output.  This seems odd since `color.ui` is supposed to automatically switch off when piping output.

In any case, though, to get just the desired commit SHA1, you could sidestep the entire issue by using `git rev-list` rather than `git log --pretty=oneline` and piping through commands to extract the SHA-1s.  That is, instead of:

```
git log --pretty=oneline --branches -- $FILE | tail -1 | cut -f 1 -d' '
```

you can use the simpler:

```
git rev-list --branches -- $FILE | tail -1
```

(unfortunately, `--reverse -n 1` to eliminate the `tail` step fails: `git rev-list` generates the list, limits it to one commit, then reverses it, which just gets you the *first* commit instead of the *last*).